# Multiple filter in filter context Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that I can use bool query and pass multiple filters however I am trying same thing using filter context query however it is not working, giving be `json_parse_exception` error and `reason: "duplicate field 'term'`

Here is my code:

```
{
  "aggs": {
  "histo": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "field": "date", 
      "interval": "1h",
    },
    "aggs": {
      "start_agg": {
        "filter": {
          "term": {"request_1":"rent"},
          "term": {"request_2": "start"}}
      },
      "deploy_agg": {
        "filter": {
          "term": {"request_1": "supporter-manager"},
          "term": {"request_2": "deploy"}
        }
      }
     }
   }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2019-12-02T15:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2019-12-03T14:59:59.999Z"
            }
          }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your json is  not valid, it contains the same key name in two places. Moreover, it's missing the ending of the array. Post one or two documents in order to test locally

Comment: hm... So I need to put `filter:[{"term":{"request_1":"rent"}}, {"term":{"request_2":"start"}}] like this?

Comment: No, the examples I've seen is not like that either https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-adjacency-matrix-aggregation.html . If you add some mock data I can look into it

Comment: I thought I could do multiple term w/o using bool query but I guess I cannot.